# .ps1: Get-Content "Cannot find Path " ... " error

Tags: powershell, script, path

So I just wrote a really really short script, which I need to replace a unique string in a txt file for all our users in our company.

```
Get-Content ("C:\Users\" -and $env:UserName -and "\desktop\Script\Test.txt") | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "ALTERTEXT", "NEUERTEXT" } | Set-Content("C:\Users\" -and $env:UserName -and "\desktop\Script\Test.txt")
```

First of all,
it worked! I tested it a few times, and it always worked. 
After the tests I didn't change the script itself. I just worked on other stuff.
But since today, I get an error:

> "Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\dohuegadmin\desktop\script\True' because it does not exist."

But actually this path does exist... and I mean, it did work!

I really searched a long time for a solution and read really many threads, but couldn't find any solutions.
Perhaps because I'm not really into ps scripting.
And I don't have that much time for this...

Anyone with any advice?

Comment: Did you happen to change all your `+` to `-and` perhaps? Change the `-and` to `+` and you'r good to go.

Comment: or even better, use `"C:\Users\$($env:UserName)\desktop\Script\Test.txt"`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thanks alot, that's an elegant way to solve the problem. Only last thing now is, after it loaded the File, it's "status" is "in use". So on the second part of my script, where it should save the new value, it says the file is already in use

Comment: `Get-Content` starts sending the content through the pipeline while reading so you are blocking yourself. One option is to use another file, another option is to force `Get-Content` to read the whole file before sending it through the pipeline. Easiest is to just surround `Get-Content` with parenthesis: `(Get-Content "C:\Users\$($env:UserName)\desktop\Script\Test.txt") | ...`

Comment: or best `$env:userprofile\desktop\script\test.txt`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers 
Thanks alot! This helped me, and it makes sense to me. I need the same filename, so I decided to use the second option:

`(Get-Content ("C:\Users\$($env:UserName)\desktop\Script\Test.txt")) | ...`

@SimonS Thanks for the advice! :)